# How to manage lxd server configuration by ansible?

Tags: ansible, containers, infrastructure-as-code

I am trying to set up the lxd global, server settings with ansible. Note, these are *not* the instance or container settings, these are the global settings of the lxd daemon. For example, `core.https_address`:

```
# lxc config show
config:
  core.https_address: 0.0.0.0:8443
```

How can I modify them with the super idempotent way by ansible modules? My impression about the docs of the relevant modules (`community.general.lxd_container`, `community.general.lxd_profile`, `community.general.lxc_container`, `community.general.lxd_project`) that they are doing everything, except this.

Answer (score 0):

I started to develop a python module for the task. It had not been a big job, but honestly I only want to change some values yet, so I finally shortcutted it with this workaround:

```
- name: lxc config set core.https_address "0.0.0.0:8443"
  ansible.builtin.shell: if [ "$(lxc config get core.https_address)" = "0.0.0.0:8443" ]; then exit 0; else lxc config set core.https_address "0.0.0.0:8443" && exit 255; fi
  register: script_res
  changed_when: script_res.rc == 255
  failed_when: script_res.rc not in [0, 255]
```

Idea is that I substitute it with a singleline shellscript. Obviously that is quite a suboptimal solution.

Comment: If a better answer appears, that will get the pipe.